# Optimization of percent match code

Tags: optimization, objective-c, ios

I have the following method that will take the car parts I searched for and match them to my car object in array. Then it tells me the percent match.

Example:

Car.h has NSSet toCarParts. toCarParts has may car parts.

My array contains 5,000 or so matches.

I will go through each one and match my parts to the car parts and calculate a percent match.  If I search for wheel, tire, rim, and Car X has wheel, tire, rim, seat, my % should be 75%.

The method does this, but take about 30 seconds on an iPhone 5 (double or triple on iPhone 4)

How can I optimize it?

I think what slows it down is that I need to open each car object, fire the faults, access the `toCarParts` set, for each part compare if it matches a part in my search array.

I also think it is slow when doing division (`counter/[carPartsArrayFaulted count]=%`).

```
-(NSMutableArray*)calculatePercentagePerFind:(NSMutableArray*)CarArray:(NSMutableArray*)partsArray{
    NSArray*defaultParts =[NSArray arrayWithArray:[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getObjectUserDefault:@"AvailableDefaultParts"]];

    int lowestPercentMatchInt=[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getIntegerUserDefault:@"lowestPercentageMatch"];

    NSMutableArray*partsFromCarArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray*returnArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *partsWithDefaultParts =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:partsArray];
    [partsWithDefaultParts addObjectsFromArray:defaultParts];


    for (int i=0; i<[CarArray count]; i++) {
        double matchCount=0;
        Car *CarResult =(Car*)[CarArray objectAtIndex:i];

                //Check if it will at least be 30% match
        double number1 = [partsWithDefaultParts count];
            number1 =(number1/[CarResult.numberOfParts doubleValue])*100;
            if (number1>lowestPercentMatchInt) {
                partsFromCarArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[CarResult toParts]allObjects]];
                NSMutableArray *faultedParts=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                for (int i =0; i<[partsFromCarArray count]; i++) {
                    CarPart*part = (CarPart*)[partsFromCarArray objectAtIndex:i];
                        [faultedParts addObject:part.name];
                }
            // for each part in the Car
            for (NSString *partInCar in partsWithDefaultParts){
                //if the search parts contain that part, add one to count
                if ([faultedParts containsObject:partInCar]) {
                    matchCount++;
                }
            }
            //Calculate percent match
            double percentMatch = matchCount;

            percentMatch =(percentMatch/[CarResult.numberOfParts doubleValue])*100;

            //if at least 30%(user default) then add the percent match to Car result
            if (percentMatch >lowestPercentMatchInt) {
                if (percentMatch>100) {
                    CarResult.percentMatch = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100.00];
                }else{
                    CarResult.percentMatch = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:percentMatch];
                }
                [returnArray addObject:CarResult];
            }
    }
    }
    NSLog(@"Percent Matched Cars = %i",[returnArray count]);
    return [self arrangeByHighestPercentMatch:returnArray];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are comparing all part against all parts, so you have a squared complexity which causes trouble for bigger numbers.

In the case that you can create your part list as **sorted list** (i.e. TreeSet in Java, not sure what is available in your language ) you can do the comparison in linear time by stepping through both lists in parallel.

An other idea is to use something like the **HashSet** in Java where the containsObject don't cost linear time as with the array or a simple list.